# AKS: Nginx ingress pod stuck in `Pending` state due to nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Today I have deployed AKS service in Azure cloud and tried to start test services on it, however faced an error that Ingress pod stuck in `Pending` state because of the following:

> 0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match node selector.

I have checked nodeSelector for Nginx ingress:

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

To fix the issue I have removed nodeSelector from deployment and now everything work as expected.

Below evidence that I'm using correct OS on my Kubernetes nodes:

[image]

Ingress version is [0.26.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases) - deployed using [manifests from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml).

So, it is clear how to fix the issue, but what is a root cause here? Is it bug or knowledge gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be a better solution to have labeled the nodes:

`kubectl label node --all kubernetes.io/os=linux`

Comment: I have edited my first response how I have resolved the issue, but your solution is also good. Thank you Suren.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Kubernetes version 1.13.10.

Starting from Kubernetes version 1.16, `beta.kubernetes.io/os` has been deprecated and now actual one is `kubernetes.io/os`. So, ingress uses parameters in accordance with latest Kubernetes release.

To permanently fix the issue, it is required to use `beta.kubernetes.io/os` parameter in version of kubernetes lower than 1.16.

[Kuberentes 1.16 release notes.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)

I have added `patch` into my pipeline to fix the issue:

```
kubectl patch deployment nginx-ingress-controller -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"beta.kubernetes.io/os":"linux"}}}}}
```

Comment: Actually, it says it got deprecated on 1.14. I have a 1.15 cluster with `kubernetes.io/os: linux` label